# How to find on circuit why it is burning

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

[image]I have done a similar design in tinkercad but I don't understand why it is not working..it is burning[image]

[image]

and the second picture is the design from a youtube video that it is working properly. I have done something wrong but I can't find it..I re-design it from youtube to the tikercad

Comment: @DKNguyen Good catch! You've saved me from thinking that moving parts to the left on the solderless breadboard makes them cooler and less likely to burn!

Comment: @jonk No, I was wrong. I just can't read breadboard :P

Comment: @DKNguyen Well, I guess its back to the old theory about bunching things to the left, then. ;)

Comment: You might want to check if those power rails on your breadboard are actually connected between left and right halves. Some aren't and require a jumper in the middle to connect the two halves.

Comment: @Yun.kon Please provide a schematic, breadboards pictures are hard to work with.

Comment: @DKNguyen hi,my english are not perfect.If I got it right you mean to use multimeter and to check with voltage the  1,2,3,4 switcher if those have volt? I have 0volt on the inputs of CD4511.If you mean that

Comment: Use multimeter to measure resistance between farthest bottom left hole and farthest bottom right hole (yes, far, far bottom right hole that is not being used) on breadboard. Does it read  nearly zero ohms?

Comment: moment I go now to do it

Comment: Some breadboards are like this: http://digital-wizard.net/images/pages/breadboard_power_lines.jpg

Comment: @DKNguyen I did it (if that you mean) .I edited the post

Comment: Are you familiar with ESD that damage may also cause these symptoms?  Do any LEDs turn ON? or too bright? if you remove the chip and verify each input pin voltage =Vdd or 0V as you might expect and output pins with resistance to gnd and if that looks Like no short circuits on outputs, then assume you have succeeded in burning your 1st chip, as we have all seen.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 If I got it right , when I use on display I mean the "8" you see in the image ,as cathode it shows me only two numbers(the number 8 and the number 9) if I play with the switchers 3 and 4.The 2 switcher it close it the led "8". If I have the 1 switcher UP(in ON) then it doesn't burn the led. Also,if I use the led as Anode it doesn't show me any number

Comment: with other words guys the switcher 1 if I use it UP(as ON) then I don't "burn" my curcuit.If I put it down that switcher it is burning..Is the 1 switcher that cause it that?His input has as 6 from CD4511 and his volt is 5V.

Comment: the first and second layouts have the top middle resistors shorted together

Comment: .. and with the outputs shorted the NPN BJTs and the nMOS transistors in the CD4511 outputs will be fighting each other (if they happen to be in opposite states).

Comment: @jsotola it must be some distance?

Comment: @jsotola amaizing man...that was the issue ..lol can you explain me why?

Comment: I’m sure you will want to make or buy a handy logic probe for finding these kinds of wiring errors faster.  Jstola is explaining the same as Dave Tweed . Each resistor must be staggered in different columns or use vertically with one lead shortened like a “radial” part

Comment: @Yun.kon not amazing ....  `can you explain me why? ` ... look to see how breadboards are constructed .... why are you not asking how the wires get connected to the IC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't line up the four resistors in the upper right like that. They all need to go into unique columns, as shown in the video.

The way you have it, four outputs of the chip are shorted directly to each other!

Comment: but thanks anyway for your answer

Comment: @Yun.kon look at the 4 horizontal resistors, not the 3 vertical ones.

Comment: yes I did that I change them-i thought he was reffering on the right not to the top .anyway thanks a lot guys